# How to find objects which are accessing a map

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern, observers

#### Context

I am writing a dashboard builder application. Users create visualizations in the dashboard which access variables defined in the dashboard to generate queries.

Here is an example.

```
Dashboard:
  variables:
     someVar: 'A'
  visualizations:
     vizA:
        query: 'select * from mytable where x = ${someVar}'
```

#### Problem:

These variables are changed by various other UI events (on these visualizations) and I need to update the visualizations which depend on these variables. For each variable how do I find the visualizations dependent on it? (I don't want an explicit observer pattern)

#### I tried this way..  (See the below code)

- All the visualizations have a block of code where they read the variables.
- Before this block is executed for a visualization, I record this visualization object in a global variable (and later clear it).
- Define all the variables on the `variables` map using `Object.defineProperty` and defined getters and setters for each of these properties.
- In the getter, try to find the current updating visualization and add it to observer list.

```
let watchers = {}, variables = {__vals: {}}
variableslist
  .forEach(function (varName) {
    variables.__vals[varName] = variables[varName];
    watchers[varName] = watchers[varName] || new Set();
    Object.definevarNameerty(variables, varName, {
      get: function () {
        let viz = car.getCurrentUpdatingVisualization();    // global variable set 
        if (viz) {
          watchers[varName].add(viz);
        }
        return variables.__vals[varName];
      },
      set: function (val) {
        variables.__vals[varName] = val;
        watchers[varName].forEach((viz) => viz.update());
      },
    });
  });
```

I have a bad feeling about this, that it might not behave as expected if some visualization calls an async code in between.

Is there a better pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, this works, and you don't have to worry about asynchronous code if "*All the visualizations have a block of code where they read the variables*" as long as that block is synchronous and you don't read the variables anywhere else. You can in fact make your getter throw an exception if any variable is accessed while no such block is active, i.e. unset your global `currentUpdatingVisualization` after the block and put an `else { throw … }` on the `if (viz)`

Comment: It seems that all your visualisations have a defined list of variables that they depend on, so I don't quite understand why you don't want to use the explicit observer pattern.

Comment: @Bergi visualizations are not predefined, users add their own variables and visualizations and events (a bar is clicked in a visualization) to the dashboard so I want to figure out the variables these visualizations depend on.

Comment: I don't mean "predefined", I mean that for any given visualisation you can get the list of variables it is using. The code that is running the visualisation knows when it will access variable, it's not like you're allowing your users to write arbitrary code that is `eval`ed?

Comment: I am allowing them to do write SQL, JS here and they can use these variables, because I have a way to achieve trust!

Comment: @MadhusoodanP I think it's a quite unreliable approach. You risk ending up with an unsupportable system quite soon. In fact, you want to add some magic in your code to make arbitrary JS and SQL work without any dependency injections. 

Technically, you can replace an object with getters with a Proxy object (as Vue does) to automatically track dependencies.

Comment: But I would think again and try to introduce certain restrictions to make it clearer. E.g. you can make your users to define a function, that accepts certain parameters and return  a certain result. Moreover, it can be a ES6 module that has only 1 default export - this function. You can also make user to export a list of variables they want to use in their code. Try not to use any global variables for user code.